# Fatal error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

so this is my code

```html
 <body>
  <section id="container" >
     <?php require 'inc/header.php';?>

    <section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="row mt">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="content-panel">
        <!-- 1ere ETAPE -->                 
                  <h1 style="text-align:center ;"> Rénitialisation  </h1>
                    <div class="etape1">
<?php 
require('inc/reni/fpdf.php'); 
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('times','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(25,7,"nom");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"prenom");
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(450,7,"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
$pdf->Ln();

        include ('inc/reni/db.php');
       $sql="SELECT * FROM table1";
        $result = $bdd->query($sql);

        while($rows=$result->fetch())
        {
            $nom = $rows[0];
            $prenom = $rows[1];
            $pdf->Cell(25,7,$nom);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$prenom);

        
            $pdf->Ln(); 
        }

$pdf->Output();?>
                    </div>

              
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
            </div><!-- /row -->
      </section><! --/wrapper -->
    </section><!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->
  </section>
<?php require 'inc/script.php';?>

  </body>
```

The error is : Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file.
i try everything like add ob_end_clean(); ob_start ();ob_end_flush(); 
and when i do this my page is empty the Pdf does not display

Comment: Please add your code here instead of pictures. You need to output the PDF *before* you send anything else to your page.

Comment: i just edit my post

Answer (score 0):

What you try to use the result it's an octet stream which sends the PDF file to your Browser to download the file. In this case you can't have an output before. Create a single file and output that PDF file without writing anything before. Then you can download the file.

That is what the error message tells you. Don't output anything before the output of the PDF file.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what should i do

Comment: make a separate file with your PDF code and output that file in that new file without any output before.

Answer (score 0):

You're already outputting something.

Usually there's an echo somewhere, or you have php code like this:

```
<HTML>
<?php // do my pdf thing ?>
```

If anything is in front of your pdf output, wether it be a space, some html, an echo, a print, you will get this error.

Even a space after a php closing tag of a pdf that was included can cause this.

```
<?php 
    class PDFWriter() {
    // some code
    }
?> <-- space here

<?php include('pdfwriter.php');
```

That's why you should omit the closing tags on pure php files so that doesn't happen.

In your case you're adding all these divs

```
<body>
  <section id="container" >
     <?php require 'inc/header.php';?>

    <section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="row mt">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="content-panel">
        <!-- 1ere ETAPE -->                 
                  <h1 style="text-align:center ;"> Rénitialisation  </h1>
                    <div class="etape1">
```

And that violates the no output sending requirement.