# How to insert data into a pdf using TCPDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am busy trying to create a pdf using TCPDF but nothing is getting displayed in the pdf, the only things are the headers for the table. so none of the data that gets called after being searched gets displayed. NB i also used a join between the two tables.

```
<?php
ob_start();
function fetch_data(){
$output="";

if(isset($_POST["btnSearch"]))
{


if (isset($_POST['txtNameSearch'])){
$search = $_POST['txtNameSearch'];

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bookstore');
$sql="SELECT * FROM order_details right join tblproduct on 
order_details.prod_id=tblproduct.prod_id WHERE id_login = $search";
$Joined_records=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Joined_records)){
    $output .='
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["order_details_id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["order_id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["prod_id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["id_login"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["quantity"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["price_per_unit"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["prod_name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["prod_descr"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["prod_cat"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["prod_price"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["prod_quan"].'</td>
        </tr>
    ';

                                            }
    return $output;                                        
                                }
}

                }



if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))
{
require_once("tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
$obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P',PDF_UNIT,PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,true,"UTF-8",false);
$obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$obj_pdf->SetTitle("product sales for a specific customerproduct sales for a 
specific customer");
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData("","", PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN,"",PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$obj_pdf->SetFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA,"",PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
$obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT,'5',PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$obj_pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$obj_pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE,10);
$obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica',"",12);
$obj_pdf->AddPage();

$content="";
$content.='
    <h3 align="center"> product sales for a specific customer </h3>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th width=9%>order_details_id</th>
            <th width=9%>order_id</th>
            <th width=9%>product_id</th>
            <th width=9%>id_login</th>
            <th width=9%>quanitity</th>
            <th width=9%>price_per_unit</th>
            <th width=9%>prod_name</th>
            <th width=25%>prod_descr</th>
            <th width=9%>prod_cat</th>
            <th width=9%>prod_price</th>
            <th width=9%>prod_quan</th>
        </tr>
';

$content .= fetch_data();
$content .= '</table>';
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);
$obj_pdf->Output("sample.pdf","I");



}
  ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>product sales for a specific customer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <h3 align="center"> Please Search for a specific customer you want to see sales for: </h3>
        <br />
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="txtNameSearch" />
        <input class="src_btn" type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" />
        </form>
            <table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
            <th>Order Details Id</th>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Login ID</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Product Price per unit</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Descrp</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity Sold</th>
            </tr> 
                <form method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="create_pdf" class="btn btn-
danger" value="create_pdf" />
            </form>





<?php
echo fetch_data();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're outputing something before your PDF.  Try to move the whole PHP code at the top BEFORE anything else.  Also see this exact same duplicate question: [Fatal error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719897/fatal-error-some-data-has-already-been-output-cant-send-pdf-file)

EDIT: Now that you put all the PHP code at the very top, if it still does the same thing, it means that there is a warning or an error in the PHP code but you cannot see it because of your ob_start().  So, to see what's going on, temporarily comment out the `ob_start();` line and put a `error_log(E_ALL);` line at the very top (on first line).  Also put a `die();` line just before the `$obj_pdf->Output("sample.pdf","I");` line.  Execute the script.  If you see ANYTHING (and I mean ANYTHING AT ALL) printed out on the page, then this is the problem and you should fix whatever error or warning that is displayed or it will never work.

Comment: please note i rephrased the question

Comment: Any update on this @MOHAMMEDAMEEN ? Please clean up and rephrase your question if I did not understand your problem, altough your inital question seems to have changed.